# How to change log4j log file under tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I'm using Tomcat 7 and Log4j 2.
I've tuned tomcat to write log4j logs (described on tomcat website), but it writes them to catalina.out file. Tried to change it in log4.properties with

log4j.appender.X.File=logs/out.log

but it doesn't work.
What else should I configure to be able to write to custom log file ?
Here is my configuration:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, X

# my personal settings
log4j.logger.com.vkhyzhniak=INFO, X

# spring and jsf support. not sure i need them
log4j.logger.com.acme=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.logger.javax.faces=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.myfaces=INFO
log4j.logger.com.sun.faces=INFO

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.X=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.X.File=logs/out.log
log4j.appender.X.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.X.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.X.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.X.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you getting any errors or warnings? where are you putting log4j.properties and log4j.jar?

Comment: i've puttet file in src/main/resources directory. File "out.log" was created, but it was empty all the time. After I restarted tomcat i noticed error, that tomcat did't load this file. I moved config file to CATALINA_HOME/lib and everything works vice versa. I mean that now i have tomcat /manager, /localhost and other logs in "out.log" and my project logs in "catalina.out".If you know how to fix this - i'll be very thankful, but any way thanks a lot!

Comment: if someone is still interested - I found the solution. The problem was in my java code. I've been using **java.util.logging.Logger** instead of **org.apache.log4j.Logger**. After refactoring I removed config file from CATALINA_HOME/lib directory and now seems that everything is fine. Hope it will help somebody ;)